# Movie about a woman who becomes obsessed with a necklace and its former owner and it kills her

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror, magical-items

A man and his wife move into a beautiful old house. He adores his wife and they are a very happy couple. Soon after moving in, the wife finds or somehow becomes enchanted with an antique necklace that somehow comes into her possession.

I remember the necklace as having a **large green stone**. If I remember correctly, the wife then becomes obsessed with the former owner of the necklace, a beautiful woman from Victorian times. The former owner of the necklace uses the wife's obsession to drain energy from her to make herself stronger or to come back to this world somehow(?)

Despite her husband's best efforts to save her, the wife dies and I believe the movie ends with the husband holding his wife's body in his arms and sobbing.

I want to say that the wife was played by Sharon Stone but nothing in her filmography I've seen seems to fit.

I saw this on TV in probably the mid 1980's in the US.

Comment: You are allowed put spaces after fullstops, and even occasional paragraphs if you would like to... This is the third question I've see exactly like this from you!  Please help us read your question so as to be better able to answer them.

Answer (score 6):

You're describing "[Judy, You're Not Yourself Today](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tales_from_the_Crypt_episodes)"; Season 2, Episode 11 of "Tales from the Crypt".

A cosmetics saleswoman (Frances Bay) visits the home of a young, vain and eccentric couple (Brian Kerwin and **Carol Kane**) and convinces the wife to try on a magic necklace that switches the wife's body with hers. The episode ends with the husband clutching the wife on the floor of their home.

[image: Judy, You're Not Yourself Today]

You can watch the full episode here;

Comment: No,this is not what I was looking for at all.It was a tv movie,not a tv show and despite the decent guess,its not what I was looking for at all.Thanks anyway.Seriously. BTW,the stone was rectangular in shape,A dark green,and very heavy.Not that adding that matters that much I know.

Comment: If you're the same user that posted the original question, you'll need to sign in using your original details and post this as a comment under my answer

Comment: @SpikeBuffyLuv And you can follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20two%20accounts,that%20you%20own%20both%20accounts.) about how to merge your accounts.